# Is there a way to check for support for specific at-rules in CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm looking for an equivelent to `@supports` but for at-rules.
So I want to be able to do

```
@supports (@counter-style) {
  things
}
```

And I want to do this using only CSS/HTML.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, the far future:

> The CSS Working Group just discussed feature detection for descriptors, and agreed to the following:
>
> RESOLVED: Add an `at-rule` function with syntax `at-rule(@keyword)` or `at-rule(@keyword; descriptor: value)`

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2463#issuecomment-1016720310

You will be able to do:

```
@supports at-rule(@foo) {
  /* @foo is supported */
}
```

---

Now and in the near future, you cannot.